# While creating a project specific gemset for a new rails application, got this error: .ruby-version is not empty, moving aside to preserve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Specifically, this is what I typed into terminal and what came back:

```
$ mkdir myapp
$ cd myapp
$ rvm use ruby-2.1.0@myapp --ruby-version --create
ruby-2.1.0 - #gemset created /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@myapp
ruby-2.1.0 - #generating myapp wrappers.
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0 with gemset myapp
.ruby-version is not empty, moving aside to preserve.
.ruby-gemset is not empty, moving aside to preserve.


$ ls -la .ruby*
-rw-rw-r--  1 danisyellis  staff   6 Jan 24 14:26 .ruby-gemset
-rw-rw-r--  1 danisyellis  staff   6 Jan 24 14:26 .ruby-gemset.01.24.2014-14:26:06
-rw-rw-r--  1 danisyellis  staff  11 Jan 24 14:26 .ruby-version
-rw-rw-r--  1 danisyellis  staff  11 Jan 24 14:26 .ruby-version.01.24.2014-14:26:06
$ cat .ruby*
myapp
myapp
ruby-2.1.0
ruby-2.1.0
```

I've searched the internet for that error message and haven't found anything that explains it so I don't know what it means. 
It almost looks like my computer ran the command twice and tried to create a duplicate?
Questions:

1. Is that what happened or was it something else?
2. If yes, why did it do that?
3. What does "moving aside to preserve" mean?
4. Is there anything I can change/clean up so that everything works properly and cleanly

Thanks so much for any help you can give! I'm pretty new to all this so answers with a decent amount of detail/hand-holding would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like a bug, please report it here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

in the mean time ignore this bug, you can remove the duplicate files quite easily:

```
rm -f .ruby-*\.*
```

Comment: do you run this from within the specific ruby directory, i.e. ../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0? I did this with no luck. I got the above error message again. I also attempted this within my app folder with no luck as well.